# Having trouble with fixed navbar not getting parrent width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I've recently started working with bootstrap and is somewhat a newbie to webdesign as well.
I've been having trouble with my navbar not enheriting the .container-fluid width, which in the end making in non-responsive. I wanted my navbar to be fixed and in "high" z-position, to overlap content. I've been searching far and low on Stack Overflow to find an answer but with no luck. Can some wiz please enlighten me?

I don't have the exact code currently but it look something like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="navbar">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
 #navbar{
 position:fixed;
 z-index:999;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 }
```

Comment: Can we please have a code snippet?

Comment: Be sure to check out this: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples -- Generally it is best to copy and paste chunks of working code, then remove what you don't need or otherwise adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a CSS Class(`navbar-fixed-top`) in bootstrap for a fixed navbar.

1. Change your first `<div>` to `<nav>` (nav is a div but it is the HTML5 standard)
2. Add the `navbar-default` & `navbar-fixed-top` to your `<nav>`
3. Nest your `container-fluid` div inside your `<nav>...</nav>`
4. Add link tags to your `<li>` items

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Then you will need to add padding to your body in your CSS file if you dont want the navbar to overlap content:

CSS:

```
body{
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

[Documentation here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

I hope this helps!

Comment: ___Note: If you want the body to have the `container-fluid` attributes you will have to add a `<div class="container-fluid"></div>` after the `</nav>`___